# Why do I get this error - Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object - Cake 2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, fatal-error

Why do I get this error?

```
Fatal Error

Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
File: /home/mycake/public_html/app/Controller/TasksController.php
Line: 7
```

I think it has something to do with using CAKE 2.0 but I think the code in my controller might be CAKE 1.3? And I have done a bit of research but I don't know how to change the code to be in CAKE 2.0. Can anyone help?

This is the TasksController.php page

```
<?php
class TasksController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'tasks';
    public function index() {
        //THIS IS THE LINE 7
        $tasks = $this->Task->find('all');
        $this->set('tasks', $tasks);
    }
}
```

If you need any more info please ask because I'm not sure how else to make it more relevant to get an answer :)

Comment: it means `Task` is not an object, according to the [`api`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-AppController.html) there is no `Task` property of `AppController`

Answer (score 1):

If you controller is called `TasksController` then it will try and instantiate the `Task` model automatically. You don’t need to manually specify it. The reason CakePHP is throwing an error is because you’ve pluralised the name (models are singular, so `Task` not `Tasks`) and are also camel-cased, meaning they start with an uppercase letter (`Task` not `task`).

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP does auto instantiation of corresponding Model if the particular controller's property `$uses` is not set, so this means you might accidentally setting the property `$uses` of your `AppController` to either `null` or `array()`.

So, check that if you have `$uses` in your `AppController` set to empty, or simply, in your `TasksController`, overwrite the value with `public $uses = array('Task');`.

Comment: I have done that but now it brings back this error `Missing Database Table

Error: Table â€˜tasksâ€™s for model Task was not found in datasource default.` and this is my Task.php page code `<?php
class Task extends AppModel {
 public $name = ‘Task’;
}`

Comment: I do have a db table called tasks too just so you know :)

Comment: So: is datasource correctly configured to point to the right database?

Comment: sorry how do I configure it correctly? at the moment the folder `datasource` is empty - but I have pointed the `database.php` correctly to the database `tasks`

Comment: Well, what he meant is the datasource in `database.php`. Share your database.php with us, so we can take a look at it. __Remember to hide all the credentials__.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the index like this:

```
class TasksController extends AppController{


    public function index(){

        $this->set('tasks', $this->Task->find('all'));
    }
```

If you get the Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object, You can put:

```
$this->loadModel('Task');
```